# Error con PYCHARM y las pruebas con unittest

Tags: python, pycharm, unittest

estoy empezando a aprender las pruebas unitarias en Python. Uso PyCharm 2023.1 (Community Edition). El caso es que todas las pruebas que hago me salen OK, incluso las que deberían fallar o dar error, sin embargo, si estas mismas pruebas las hago con el IDLE de Python, si que funcionan. Pongo dos ejemplos, uno de failed y otro de error:

```
import unittest

# Test failed

class Pruebas(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        raise AssertionError()
unittest.main()
```

Este test de failed me da este resultado:

> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
>
> OK
>
> Process finished with exit code 0
>
> Empty suite
>
> Empty suite

```
import unittest

# Test error

class Pruebas(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        3/0
unittest.main()
```

Este test de error me da el siguiente resultado:

> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
>
> OK
>
> Process finished with exit code 0
>
> Empty suite
>
> Empty suite

He revisado la configuración de Pycharm, pero no he encontrado qué es lo que puede fallar porque, de hecho, no falla nada incluso cuando debería.

Muchas gracias y un saludo!!